# Getting last word of third line

Tags: javascript

I found a script which outputs the last words of each line in a paragraph. Can someone help out to only output the last word of the third line?

```
<div id="flop">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>

<script>
var d = document.getElementById('flop');
var t = d.innerHTML;
var w = t.split(' ');       

d.innerHTML = w[0];
var height = d.clientHeight;
for(var i = 1; i < w.length; i++){
    d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + ' ' + w[i];

    if(d.clientHeight > height){
        height = d.clientHeight;
        console.log(w[i-1]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Keep track of how many times you've seen a word that satisfies the condition and when you see the third one, use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter

```
d.innerHTML = w[0];
var lineCount = 1;
var height = d.clientHeight;
for(var i = 1; i < w.length; i++){
    d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + ' ' + w[i];

    if(d.clientHeight > height){
        height = d.clientHeight;
        if (lineCount == 3) {
            console.log(w[i-1]);
        }
        lineCount++;
    }
}
```

To wrap it in a `<div>`:

```
for(var i = 1; i < w.length; i++){
    d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + ' ' + w[i];

    if(d.clientHeight > height){
        height = d.clientHeight;
        if (lineCount == 3) {
            d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML.replace(/\b([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)$/, '<div>$1</div> $2');
            console.log(w[i-1]);
        }
        lineCount++;
    }
}
```

Note that adding a DIV is likely to change the layout, which could change the last words.

Comment: Do you also have a clue how to wrap the last word of the third line into e.g. a `<div>`?